# Rotate line around center

Tags: rotation, pivot, trigonometry, line-drawing

I have to use a propriertary graphics-engine for drawing a line. I can rotate the whole drawing by its origin point (P1). What I want, is to rotate it around its center point(M). So basically that it looks like L_correct instead of L_wrong.

I think, it should be possible to correct it, by moving it from P1 to P2. But I cannot figure out what formula could be used, to determine the distance. It must probably involve the angle, width and height...

So basically my question is, if there is a function to determine x2 and y2 based on my available data?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a primitive method that rotates a drawing by any given angle `phi`. What you want is to use that primitive to rotate a drawing `D` around a point `M` instead. Here is a sketch of how to proceed.

1. Translate you drawing by `-M`, i.e., apply the transformation `T(P) = P - M` to all points `P` in your drawing. Let `T(D)` be the translation of `D`.
2. Now use the primitive to rotate `T(D)` by the desired angle `phi`. Let `R(T(D))` be the result.
3. Now translate the previous result by `M` and get the rotated drawing. In other words, use the transformation `T'(P) = P + M`.

Note that in step 1 above `M` is mapped to the origin `0`, where the rotation primitive is known to work. After rotating in step 2, the opposite translation of step 3 puts back the drawing on its original location as this time `0` is mapped to `M`.