# How can I rotate a line segment around its center by 90 degrees?

Tags: algorithm

Since I'm really bad with math and don't understand a word of [this paper on the topic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html), and [this answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685178/5536767) doesn't explain it clearly enough for me, could someone show me the algorithm, in pseudo-code, for rotating a line segment, say charted at (50,40) - (50,120) around its center point (by 90 degrees)? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Wikipedia has an example of how to use a rotation matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

90 degrees is an easy special case.  Lets say you have a line from `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)`:

```
//find the center
cx = (x1+x2)/2;
cy = (y1+y2)/2;

//move the line to center on the origin
x1-=cx; y1-=cy;
x2-=cx; y2-=cy;

//rotate both points
xtemp = x1; ytemp = y1;
x1=-ytemp; y1=xtemp; 

xtemp = x2; ytemp = y2;
x2=-ytemp; y2=xtemp; 

//move the center point back to where it was
x1+=cx; y1+=cy;
x2+=cx; y2+=cy;
```

Comment: @Viziionary: You really don't need to read a research paper to turn a line by 90 degrees. This answer is the easiest way to do. The only improvement is that `cx` and `cy` are also removed by substituting their values directly everywhere.

Comment: as a reminder, x goes from left to right, y from bottom to top, and angle anticlockwise in radians is PI / 2, and points are expressed as (x, y)

Answer (score 4):

For a line segment, you could use a function like this one:

```
function rotate(a, b, angle) {
    // a and b are arrays of length 2 with the x, y coordinate of
    // your segments extreme points with the form [x, y]

    midpoint = [
        (a[0] + b[0])/2,
        (a[1] + b[1])/2
    ]

    // Make the midpoint the origin
    a_mid = [
        a[0] - midpoint[0],
        a[1] - midpoint[1]
    ]
    b_mid = [
        b[0] - midpoint[0],
        b[1] - midpoint[1]
    ]

    // Use the rotation matrix from the paper you mentioned
    a_rotated = [
        cos(angle)*a_mid[0] - sin(angle)*a_mid[1],
        sin(angle)*a_mid[0] + cos(angle)*a_mid[1]
    ]
    b_rotated = [
        cos(angle)*b_mid[0] - sin(angle)*b_mid[1],
        sin(angle)*b_mid[0] + cos(angle)*b_mid[1]
    ]

    // Then add the midpoint coordinates to return to previous origin
    a_rotated[0] = a_rotated[0] + midpoint[0]
    a_rotated[1] = a_rotated[1] + midpoint[1]
    b_rotated[0] = b_rotated[0] + midpoint[0]
    b_rotated[1] = b_rotated[1] + midpoint[1]

    // And the rotation is now done
    return [a_rotated, b_rotated]
}
```

How you would use it:

```
// In your case:
a = [50, 40]
b = [50, 120]
angle_degrees = 90
angle_radians = angle_degrees*pi/180

rotated = rotate(a, b, angle_radians)
// Rotated[0] will be your new a coordinates, in your case [90, 80]
// Rotated[1] will be your new b coordinates, in your case [10, 80]
```

Comment: Could be more easy for the special case of 90° as shown by @MattTimmermans but definitely also a very useful answer. I like that you used the technique of the paper OP mentioned and explained it with comments.